# Doubling adverbs for emphasis?

Tags: adverb

Newbie question. Would it be German to double an adverb for emphasis, such as "ich bin sehr, sehr alt"?  Or is this just wrong?  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can build sentences like this

Comment: A bit more of an explanation would be helpful: is this informal, good style, etc. Punctuation wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 2):

Verbreitet ist das Verdoppeln von *sehr*:

> Ich bin sehr, sehr müde.

Technisch möglich, aber nicht üblich, ist das Verdoppeln anderer Adverbien

> *Das tut mir arg, arg leid.
>
> *Das tut mir schrecklich, schrecklich weh.
>
> *Ich hab dich unglaublich, unglaublich lieb.
>
> *Das gefällt mir wirklich, wirklich gut.

Man versteht solche Sätze, und sie sind auch nicht falsch im Sinne von Grammatik oder Syntax. Jedoch wüsste ich nicht, dass ich so etwas je in alltäglicher Sprachpraxis gehört hätte.

Ich vermute, der Grund ist, dass man für solche Betonungen andere, nämlich lexikalische Mittel hat. Anstatt das Adverb zu verdopplen, nimmt man ein anderes, stärkeres:

> Das tut mir fürchterlich leid.
>
> Das tut mir höllisch weh.
>
> Ich hab dich granatenmäßig lieb.
>
> Das gefällt mir saumäßig gut.

Oder aber man wählt gesonderte lexikalische Verstärker, die keine Dopplungen sind:

> Das tut mir ganz fürchterlich leid.
>
> Das finde ich ein klitzekleines bisschen unangebracht.